# Website does not click or scroll after adding threejs canvas animation

Tags: svg, responsive-design, three.js, html5-canvas, responsive

My website [truptidesale.com](http://truptidesale.com/) has animation which is created using three.js on canvas. i have given background image to canvas and made position as absolute and z-index -1 so that my navigation bar will be on top of canvas. This works very well on my desktop but website does not scroll or cant click on navigation bar when i access website on iphone or android phone.

can somebody please help me to make this work on mobile? Thank you so much.

Comment: At the very end of html code of your page, there is a closing `</script>` tag, which doesn't have opening `<script>` tag. The tag I'm saying about is right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for noticing that. I have added <script> opening tag to the script but still issue is not resolved.

Comment: in `snowfall.js`, there are two functions about touch events: `onDocumentTouchStart` and `onDocumentTouchMove`. Inside those functions try to comment lines with `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Hi prisoner849, It worked. Thank you so much.. it works like a charm !! :)